# Telerik Editor doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I

1. Downloaded open-source version of Telerik
2. Put Telerik css and js in appropriate folders in project
3. Added reference to Telerik dll
4. Wrote HTML http://pastebin.com/FzQDitzA

And I got this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/testgu.png/

It is all fine but when I cannot type text in this control and comboboxes don't work too

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a ScriptRegistrar which is responsible for initializing the editor and rendering the required JavaScript files.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        @{ Html.Telerik().Editor()
           .Name("editor").Render();
           }
    </div>
   @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar())
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you bundled them in your bundle config and added them to the root of your page?

like this in your bundleconfig:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
        ));
```

and then call on your _Layouts.cshtml or so this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

if it still doesnt work, reach out (also please check if you have a **jQuery** version which works with your open-source version)